# Are there any disadvantages to 'fast travel'?

Tags: the-witcher-3

AFAIK it takes the same amount of time if I run by foot as if I fast travel the same way.

Do you know any disadvantage to 'fast travel'?
*Its' obvious that I can't collect any herbs or find some undetected treasures if I hop from one waypoint to another.*

But do I lose something?
Or is there anything not refreshing during the fast travel time?

Comment: You wont miss anything but the things you already listed. So Quests Herbs treasures and so on. It makes no difference if you travel and time goes by or if you meditate neither do you loose anything.

Answer (score 5):

There is a concoction (can't recall the name at the moment) which increases Geralt HP for every foe killed. But the extra HP gets reset when you fast travel.

Also you might miss some quests on the road (bandits, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't lose out on anything. Honestly there are so many alchemy herbs, flowers and other things that you'll find on your journey that I recommend fast traveling as much as you can.

The only thing you'd really miss out on is discovering an unmarked cave entrance or a random group of enemies.